# GeoServer does not generate cache

Tags: geoserver, tiles, geowebcache

I published simple polygon (shp) as a WMS and enabled caching. In geowebcache I created new task for caching as a test (zoom levels 0 and 1, EPSG 900913, type of operation: "generate missing tiles") and submitted. The task was submitted but no cache was generated! There was no specifed folder with tiles in the gwc directory.

What could be the reason for the absence of tiles? In other words, why generation of tiles doesn't work?

[image: task submitted]

The log:
2017-01-17 16:29:29,782 INFO [seed.SeedTask] - GWC Seeder Thread-11 begins seeding layer : test:mende
2017-01-17 16:29:29,784 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2017-01-17 16:29:29,784 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Service WMS is disabled
    at org.geoserver.ows.DisabledServiceCheck.serviceDispatched(DisabledServiceCheck.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.fireServiceDispatchedCallback(Dispatcher.java:576)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.service(Dispatcher.java:571)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:257)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.GWC.dispatchOwsRequest(GWC.java:1207)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.dispatchGetMap(GeoServerTileLayer.java:618)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:563)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.seedTile(GeoServerTileLayer.java:757)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.SeedTask.doActionInternal(SeedTask.java:136)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.GWCTask.doAction(GWCTask.java:76)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:36)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)

Comment: please look in the log file and see what the error message is and then paste that message (as text) into your question.

Comment: @iant thanks, and where this log file should be?

Comment: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/troubleshooting.html#leveraging-geoserver-own-log

Comment: @iant Thanks! Here is the message:                                                                   layer test:mende in CRS EPSG:900913. Assuming full GridSet bounds. (null)
2017-01-17 14:53:19,335 WARN [gwc.layer] - Can't compute bounds for tile

Comment: edit the question, please - also that is not an error

Comment: @iant ok, how should I edit the question? I'm sorry, maybe I'm doing something wrong. I can add the following as far as I'm not sure what exactly I need to publish: 2017-01-17 14:57:34,183 INFO [seed.SeedTask] - GWC Seeder Thread-3 begins seeding layer : test:mende
2017-01-17 14:57:34,185 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2017-01-17 14:57:34,185 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Service WMS is disabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message: `Service WMS is disabled` you have turned the WMS service off (or your user does not have permission to use it).

It should all work if you turn the WMS back on or sort out the permissions for the service.